# Posting Photo to FB results in Requires upload file error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload, photo

I have the following code which I think is very close to working but I keep getting the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

but I cannot figure out how to specify the upload file...   I have tried both image and source, both give the same error.   Any thoughts, help, suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling with this for a couple of days and it seems like it should not be this hard...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Photo Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$app_id = "MY APP ID GOES HERE";
$app_secret = "MY APP SECRET GOES HERE";
$post_login_url = "MY URL GOES HERE";

$album_name = "Test Album";
$album_description = "Blah Blah event Photos";

$photo_source = realpath("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Lighthouse.jpg");
$photo_message = 'Here is the lighthouse';

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
echo "code ==>" . $code . '<br/><br/>';

//Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission
if(empty($code)){
    $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
        . "client_id=" . $app_id
        . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url)
        . "&scope=publish_stream,user_photos";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url .
        "'</script>");
}
else {
    $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
        . "access_token?"
        . "client_id=" .  $app_id
        . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
        . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
        . "&code=" . $code;
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];
    echo "access_token ==>" . $access_token . '<br/><br/>';

    // Create a new album

    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?"
        . "access_token=". $access_token;

    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'name' => $album_name,
            'message' => $album_description
        )
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'=> 'POST',
            'header'=> 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, $context));

    // Get the new album ID
    $album_id = $result->id;    //upload photo
    echo "album_id ==>" . $album_id . '<br/><br/>';


    // Upload the photo


    $args = array( 'message' => $photo_message,
             'image'   => $photo_source
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos?
                    access_token='.$access_token;
    echo "url ==>" . $url . '<br/><br/>';

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "data ==>" . $data . "<br>";


}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the config var `fileUpload` to `true` when creating a new instance of the Facebook class as described in the [documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setFileUploadSupport/). And you also need the photo_upload permission ;-)

```
require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config[‘secret’] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$config[‘fileUpload’] = true; // <-- set this to 'true' otherwise it won't work

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
```

Comment: You don't have to set it in the config, you can set it after you've initialized the Facebook object, with "$facebook->setFileUploadSupport = true". You also don't need "File_upload" but "publish_stream" permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using file name instead of file itself in your Graph API call.

You should prefix file name with `@`

```
$args = array( 'message' => $photo_message,
    'image' => '@'.$photo_source
);
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, I know that @ suppresses error messages so I dont see that fixing the problem. 
I changed my code to:

inline `$args = array( 'message' => $photo_message, 
                       'image' => file($photo_source)
                     )
`
and now it is complaining that my file doesnt exist on the server. I dont want a server file, I want 
a local file? What am I missing??

Comment: OK, I think I found my answer to this.  It appears that when they state that fopen opens a local file they mean local to where the script is running, in my case the go daddy server.   I am guessing that this is for security reasons, I cant think of any other reason for it.   Can someone confirm this for me?  I think I am going to have to approach this from a different angle if it is correct.

Comment: @JesseCreamer if you want local file and one from server than you need to upload one to server first. And yes by uploading files generally from same server the script located on (actually it may be a lot complicated flow, and the reason for this not only security reasons. But this is another question)