# Posting Photo to FB results in Requires upload file error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload, photo

OK, I am at the end of my rope here LOL.   I have the following code which I know is reading the jpg file as long as I put it in the tmp folder of my website.   However, I am still getting the annoying error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

What am I missing???? It has to be something simple but I will darned if I can figure it out.  Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Photo Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$app_id = "APP ID HERE";
$app_secret = "APP SECRET HERE";
$post_login_url = "LOGIN IN URL HERE";

$album_name = "My Silly Album";
$album_description = "Blah Blah Photos";

$photo_source = "tmp/Lighthouse.jpg";
$photo_message = 'Here is the lighthouse';

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
echo "code ==>" . $code . '<br/><br/>';

//Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission
if(empty($code)){
    login($app_id, $post_login_url);
}
else {
    $access_token = getAccessToken($app_id, $post_login_url, $app_secret, $code);
    echo "access_token ==>" . $access_token . '<br/><br/>';

    $album_id = createAlbum($access_token, $album_name, $album_description);

    echo "album_id ==>" . $album_id . '<br/><br/>';

    uploadPhoto($access_token, $album_id, $photo_source, $photo_message);


}

function login($app_id, $post_login_url){

    echo '***** login' . '<br/><br/>';

    $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
        . "client_id=" . $app_id
        . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url)
        . "&scope=publish_stream,user_photos";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url .
        "'</script>");
}

function getAccessToken($app_id, $post_login_url, $app_secret, $code){

    echo '***** getAccessToken' . '<br/><br/>';

    $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
        . "access_token?"
        . "client_id=" .  $app_id
        . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
        . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
        . "&code=" . $code;
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    return($params['access_token']);

}

function createAlbum($access_token, $album_name, $album_description){
    // Create a new album

    echo '***** createAlbum' . '<br/><br/>';

    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?"
        . "access_token=". $access_token;

    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'name' => $album_name,
            'message' => $album_description
        )
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'=> 'POST',
            'header'=> 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, $context));

    // Return the new album ID
    return($result->id);
}

function uploadPhoto($access_token, $album_id, $photo_source, $photo_message){
    // Upload the photo

    echo '***** uploadPhoto' . '<br/><br/>';
    echo 'photo_source ==> ' . $photo_source . '<br/>photo_message ==> ' . $photo_message . '<br/>';

    $fh = fopen("$photo_source","r") or die("can't open $photo_source: $php_errormsg");;
    while (!feof ($fh))
    {
       $buffer = fgets($fh, 4096);
       $file[] = $buffer;
    }

    fclose ($fh);

    $args = array( 'message' => $photo_message,
                   'source'  => $file
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos?access_token='.$access_token;
    echo "url ==>" . $url . '<br/><br/>';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "data ==>" . $data . "<br>";

    return($data);

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of your question you posted 2 days ago (which in turn almost identical to your question from 22dec). Why?

Comment: I am sorry if I posted wrong, the code had changed and the error on the first one was different.   So, yes... it was the same problem as the second one but the code had changed and I wasnt sure the best way to reask with the new code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting Photo to FB results in Requires upload file error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639499/posting-photo-to-fb-results-in-requires-upload-file-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked your script. You need to make these changes and the cde will work correctly! 100% It worked for me!

```
$args = array( 'message' => $photo_message,
         'image'   => '@'.realpath($photo_source)
);
```

And of course i deleted this section:

```
$fh = fopen("$photo_source","r") or die("can't open $photo_source: $php_errormsg");;
    while (!feof ($fh))
    {
       $buffer = fgets($fh, 4096);
       $file[] = $buffer;
    }

fclose ($fh);
```

Comment: Wow, are you kidding me!!!   I thought I had tried this with no luck!   I really appreciate your help, finally I have this working!!  This started as an experiment and ended up as a life mission LOL   I knew I was so close!  Thank You! Thank You! THank You!

Comment: Can you kindly tell what's so specific about appending '@' to real path of picture ?