# Javascript: Upload image from Canvas to FB via Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, html5-canvas, multipartform-data

I am composing an image in a canvas, I get the **base64** image data by using `canvas.toDataURL('png')` and trimming the additional information.

```
 var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('png');
 var escapedBase64Data = dataUrl.replace("data:image/png;base64,","");
```

After that I try to post to facebook using:

```
FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', { source:data});
```

Photos (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) has a source property. This is where you will place the data content (**multipart/form-data**) of your photo.

I convert my **base64** encoded data to  **multipart/form-data** by specifying the headers.

The result looks like this:

```
--0.2242348059080541
Content-Disposition: file; name="file"; filename="image.png"
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAH0CAYAAADL1t+KAAAbBElEQVR4Xu3dP4jre0LG4V2xsFVYEKy
...    
QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

--0.2242348059080541--
```

After I complete the FB api call I receive the following error:

```
Object {message: "(#324) Requires upload file", type: "OAuthException", code: 324}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't worked in facebook graph api. But found a simillar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639499/posting-photo-to-fb-results-in-requires-upload-file-error. Check if it helps

Comment: The other question is about img uploading from PHP and the need to enable setFileUpload support, in JS it is not the case.

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: This answer worked for me: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/16439233/1472477

Comment: Anybody coming from Google, might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21145106/808734) useful. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Here a working code example :

```
var boundary = '----ThisIsTheBoundary1234567890';
var formData = '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="' + filename + '"\r\n';
formData += 'Content-Type: ' + mimeType + '\r\n\r\n';

for (var i = 0; i < imageData.length; ++i)
{
    formData += String.fromCharCode(imageData[ i ] & 0xff);
}

formData += '\r\n';
formData += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"\r\n\r\n';
formData += f.message + '\r\n'
formData += '--' + boundary + '--\r\n';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + authToken, true);
xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
    // error managment
};
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

//Send the request
xhr.sendAsBinary(formData);
```

Comment: Did you get this to work? I get an error, and this works on Firefox, but not Chrome, probably because of the sendAsBinary() not being prototyped. Thoughts?

Comment: try to launch chrome like this : 

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
chrome.exe "PATHTOYOURPAGE" --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution:

```
const dataURItoBlob = (dataURI) => {
    let byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    let ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    let ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ia], {
        type: 'image/jpeg'
    });
}
const upload = async (response) => {
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
    let blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('access_token', response.authResponse.accessToken);
    formData.append('source', blob);

    let responseFB = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos`, {
        body: formData,
        method: 'post'
    });
    responseFB = await responseFB.json();
    console.log(responseFB);
};
document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click', () => {
    FB.login((response) => {
        //TODO check if user is logged in and authorized publish_actions
        upload(response);
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'})
})
```

Source: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-photo-upload-from-canvas/